# asp.net changing Master Page section css from Content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have the following code in my master page:

```
<div id="body" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
        <section runat="server" id="sectionMainContent" class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
        </section>
    </div>
```

For one specific content page I would like to change the class value of the `<section>` above to something like `class="content-wrapper-full-width main-content clear-fix"`

How can I access the `<section>`'s attributes from codebehind of the content page and modify its value?

Comment: have you added `<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/YourMasterPage.master" %>` in your Content Page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a public property in your master which gets/sets the class:

```
// sectionMainContent is a HtmlGenericControl in codebehind
public String SectionCssClass
{
    get { return sectionMainContent.Attributes["class"]; }
    set { sectionMainContent.Attributes["class"] = value; }
}
```

Now you can cast the master to the correct type and access this property in your contentpage:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    SiteMaster master = this.Master as SiteMaster; // replace with correct type
    if(master != null)
        master.SectionCssClass = "content-wrapper-full-width main-content clear-fix";
}
```

Side-note: you can use the [`@Master` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228274%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to use the `Master` property in your content-page strongly typed. Then you have compile time safety and you don't need to cast it to the actual type:

In your content-page(replace with actual type):

```
<%@ MasterType  VirtualPath="~/Site.Master"%>
```

Now this works directly:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Master.SectionCssClass = "content-wrapper-full-width main-content clear-fix";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `FindControl()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx) from code behind with something like :

```
((HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("FeaturedContent")).attributes["class"] = "content-wrapper-full-width main-content clear-fix";
```

Comment: This also worked but just had to change the HtmlElement to HtmlGenericControl

Comment: You also have to use `attributes["class"]` since a `HtmGnericControl` has no `CssClass` property. (`HtmlElement` is a winforms control)

Comment: Both thanks for your comments, I improved my answer.